# Combine data if they have the same host

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First of all, I'm sorry in advance for my English.

If I have a table likes this (2x5)

> Shop A | orange
>
> Shop A | apple
>
> Shop A | mango
>
> Shop B | orange
>
> Shop B | apple

And I want to reference them into this (using formulas) (2x2)

> Shop A |     orange, apple, mango
>
> Shop B |     orange, apple

Thank you

Comment: Forget to quote, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This isn't easy via code to my knowledge. You can get the result with a bit of work but it's messy and manual.

I am assuming your data is in columns A and B.

First, I would create two headings in D1 and E1, called "Shop A" and "Shop B"
Next, I would type just 1 apostrophe (the ' symbol) into D2 and E2. This **will not display** but it stops excel putting a 0 in each empty result later on.

Then I would put the following formula in D3:

```
=IF($A1=D$1,D2&" "&$B1,D2)
```

What this does is the following:

1. If column A for a given row contains the same "Shop" as the row
   we're looking at, then...
2. Join the string from the result above, place a space after it, and then add the value from column B
3. Else, just carry over the previous result value from the row above.

I would then drag this across to E3, which for it becomes:

```
=IF($A1=E$1,E2&" "&$B1,E2)
```

I can then drag these two cells down (that is, highlight D3 and E3 and drag them down).

Drag it down as long as you need to completely cover the original number of rows (in this case, 5). The last entry will be the concatenated string of each column. For your case, you end up with:

```
 orange apple mango | orange apple
```

Copy these two strings and **paste value** them into another cell. You can then copy these again and transpose them if you want them one above the other rather than side by side, i.e.:

```
orange apple mango
orange apple
```

Then just enter the original columns (or copy D1 and E1 and transpose them).

Note that the strings will have a space at the start of them due to the ' we put in the first cell. If you want to trim this, just use the `TRIM()` function on the result to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Hopefully this helps. As I said, it's very labour intensive but I have never found a good way to concatenate strings conditionally in excel without diving in to writing VBA.

Note, I do not use the CONCATENATE() function because it does not insert the space. You could if you did:

```
=IF($A1=D$1,CONCATENATE(D2," ",$B1),D2)
```

It works out the same as just merging them as I did.